# After clearing logs Dag is in running state but task not getting scheduled/executed

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have airflow (v1.10.4) running in Kubernetes cluster using Celery Executor. We are using RDS Postgres as an external metadata db.

Problem Statement: All dags are getting scheduled and run on time but the problem happens when we clear any log (old run) to re-run the pipeline Airflow puts this Dag in running state but none of the tasks gets executed. We also saw when we re-mark those cleared logs as success Airflow schedules the next run but none of the tasks get executed (none of the tasks goes into queue or running state).

The dag in question has depends_on_past=True and catchup=True.

Can anyone know what's going wrong here?

[image: see this screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/149428/taylor-edmiston can you help ^